# New profile page design devoured my gold badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-profile

I have four gold badges on Arqade and very proud of them. However, I just noticed they are all missing from [my new profile page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7652/shadow-wizard?tab=profile)!

> [image]

Can I please get them back? :)

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Looks like this was fixed. Also, you have 8 now!

[image: Gold Badges]